# How to get the access_token from Oauth 2 authentication without it having to be displayed in the URL?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, access-token, foursquare

I am using Foursquare API in my web application using angular 4. I want to Log In user and get the access token for that user from API. I followed these steps from the official foursquare documentation-
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth . I was successful in getting the access token as a fragment in my applications URL as "http://localhost/home#access_token=xxx". But the access token is publicly visible in my apps URL.

How can I get the access_token without it having to be displayed in the URL?

Comment: Well then you have to implement the Web Applications Code Flow, instead of the Web Applications Token Flow ...

Comment: _“But the access token is publicly visible in my apps URL”_ - and you think that would be a problem because …?

Comment: Only that access token is needed for forming api requests to Foursquare API, so if it is available in URL anyone can get the access token@CBroe

Comment: Who is “anyone”? How many people in the world have access to what you are currently seeing in the address bar of _your_ browser?

Comment: I mean its also available in browser history.@CBroe

Comment: Not if you replace the history entry as soon as you arrive on that URL ...

Comment: Yeah is there a way to remove the fragment after fetching it in my component?@CBroe

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: I will try to do that...Thank you @CBroe